# Ruby on Rails, db commands missing from rake

Tags: command-line, ruby, rails

I am trying to create a database with the following command:

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

but, that command is missing along with all the other db commands. The error I get is:

```
rake aborted!

Don't know how to build task 'db:create' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)

/root/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I do `rake -T`, I get the following output:

```
rake about                              # List versions of all Rails frameworks and the environment
rake app:template                       # Applies the template supplied by LOCATION=(/path/to/template) or URL
rake app:update                         # Update configs and some other initially generated files (or use just update:configs or update:bin)
rake assets:clean[keep]                 # Remove old compiled assets
rake assets:clobber                     # Remove compiled assets
rake assets:environment                 # Load asset compile environment
rake assets:precompile                  # Compile all the assets named in config.assets.precompile
rake cache_digests:dependencies         # Lookup first-level dependencies for TEMPLATE (like messages/show or comments/_comment.html)
rake cache_digests:nested_dependencies  # Lookup nested dependencies for TEMPLATE (like messages/show or comments/_comment.html)
rake dev:cache                          # Toggle development mode caching on/off
rake initializers                       # Print out all defined initializers in the order they are invoked by Rails
rake log:clear                          # Truncates all/specified *.log files in log/ to zero bytes (specify which logs with LOGS=test,deve...
rake middleware                         # Prints out your Rack middleware stack
rake notes                              # Enumerate all annotations (use notes:optimize, :fixme, :todo for focus)
rake notes:custom                       # Enumerate a custom annotation, specify with ANNOTATION=CUSTOM
rake restart                            # Restart app by touching tmp/restart.txt
rake routes                             # Print out all defined routes in match order, with names
rake secret                             # Generate a cryptographically secure secret key (this is typically used to generate a secret for c...
rake stats                              # Report code statistics (KLOCs, etc) from the application or engine
rake test                               # Runs all tests in test folder except system ones
rake test:db                            # Run tests quickly, but also reset db
rake test:system                        # Run system tests only
rake time:zones[country_or_offset]      # List all time zones, list by two-letter country code (`rails time:zones[US]`), or list by UTC off...
rake tmp:clear                          # Clear cache, socket and screenshot files from tmp/ (narrow w/ tmp:cache:clear, tmp:sockets:clear,...
rake tmp:create                         # Creates tmp directories for cache, sockets, and pids
rake yarn:install                       # Install all JavaScript dependencies as specified via Yarn

Ruby version: 2.6.1p33
Rails version: 5.2.2
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I see you are running rbenv, try to run: `rbenv rehash` and try again or otherwise start new terminal and try running your command again.